# Silverlight OOB - own chrome with Windows 7 docking behaviour

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-7, silverlight-oob

I'm creating Silverlight OOB application with its own chrome (title bar, minimize, maximize buttons and so on). I've implemented the resizing functionality and everything works quite good.

Still I would like to add one more functionality. I would like that my app has good docking behavior in **Windows 7 OS** - maximizing on docking to the top of the screen, changing size to the half of the screen on docking to right or left.

How can I do this? I will be appreciated for any help.

Comment: There's just no point left in using Silverlight if you want this kind of behavior.  Just write a WPF app instead.

Comment: Not so bad suggestion ;) But theoretically I would like to run this app on Mac (then this behavior of course shouldn't be available). Plus I don't want to rewrite it right now. I thought that maybe somebody has found a solution that emulates this thing.